# Create printable daily schedule/document with Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I have to create a java program that builds a "tidy" daily schedule for a sports arena. 
The program takes in an excel file with a list of "untidy" daily bookings with the following information:

- Start Time
- End Time
- Court
- Client

I can read in this information and store it in "BookingObjects".

My question is this:

What is an elegant way to create a printable schedule output, similar to schedules displayed by Microsoft Outlook for example, with time as the rows and which court the booking is on in the columns. The schedule does not need to be interactive, just needs to be printable through the program's GUI and if it can be displayed within the GUI this is also a bonus?

Answer (score 1):

We've recently made the move to [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/), the main reason was we were producing the reports in PDF, Excel and to the printer, all of which had to execute through different code and different libraries.  Jasper Reports has allowed us to go through a single engine.

While not perfect, it does an outstanding job across different export options.

It does have a small learning curve, but the basics allow you to deliver a `List` of objects which you can then access from within the report and populate your view.

Equally, you can simply connect a SQL data source to it directly

Answer (score 0):

Printing is one of the sore spots in Java. What you can try is create a UI with a table (see the [Swing trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for examples) and then [print that table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html).

The problems will start when the table doesn't fit on a single page of paper. If it's longer, then some lines will be printed on the margin (half of it will appear on the previous page and the lower half on the next page). If it's wider, ... let's not go there.

Alternatively, you can try to create a PDF using tools like [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/) or [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/). These work better but it will take some time to learn how they work.